# detect duplicated rows in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

In my gridview I have some rows that are duplicated, and I want to show these rows in red color, if the first 4 columns of these rows are resemble then these rows are duplicated.
for example in this picture the second and third rows should turn to a red color:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    For i = 0 To GridView2.Rows.Count - 1
        If (GridView2.Rows(i).Cells(0).Text = GridView2.Rows(i + 1).Cells(0).Text And GridView2.Rows(i).Cells(1).Text = GridView2.Rows(i + 1).Cells(1).Text And GridView2.Rows(i).Cells(3).Text = GridView2.Rows(i + 1).Cells(3).Text And GridView2.Rows(i).Cells(4).Text = GridView2.Rows(i + 1).Cells(4).Text) Then
            GridView2.Rows(i).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

However this code didn't work for me, any other suggestions to achieve this Please!

Thank you your time!

Comment: why don't you filter the datasource(might be datatable/dataset) before binding to GridView2 ? By the way where you are defining this code ? Give your complete code.

Comment: Use `AndAlso` instead of `And`. Also, the last row has no _next_ row which causes an exception if you try to access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You sre using datatable to fill datagridview the you can use defaultview
or else you can loop through all datagridview items

```
For i = 0 To GridView2.Rows.Count - 1
    For j As integer = 0 To GridView2.Rows.Count - 1
        If Not i = j Then
            If (GridView2.Rows(i).Cells(0).Text = GridView2.Rows(j).Cells(0).Text And GridView2.Rows(i).Cells(1).Text = GridView2.Rows(j).Cells(1).Text And GridView2.Rows(i).Cells(3).Text = GridView2.Rows(j).Cells(3).Text And GridView2.Rows(i).Cells(4).Text = GridView2.Rows(j).Cells(4).Text) Then
            GridView2.Rows(i).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
            End If
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write data formatting code in `RowDataBound` event like below.

```
Protected Sub GridView2_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As GridView, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView2.RowDataBound

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Dim idxPrev As Integer = e.Row.RowIndex - 1
        If 1 <= e.Row.RowIndex Then
            If e.Row.Cells(0).Text = sender.Rows(idxPrev).Cells(0).Text AndAlso
                e.Row.Cells(1).Text = sender.Rows(idxPrev).Cells(1).Text AndAlso
                e.Row.Cells(3).Text = sender.Rows(idxPrev).Cells(3).Text AndAlso
                e.Row.Cells(4).Text = sender.Rows(idxPrev).Cells(4).Text Then
                e.Row.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
                sender.Rows(idxPrev).ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            End If
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```